# Is there any scream detect sensor or scream recognition program?

Tags: sensors, open-source

I'm developing smart IoT product which will be placed on underground parking lot.
Among the various feature, one require **scream detection**.

I heard that there are several feature includes scream detection. eg. smart cctv...

I struggled with Google to find those, but I couldn't.
I need your help.

Are there any **sensors can detect screaming** or **open-source scream** recognition program?

Comment: I have a feeling you're into doing your own R&D here, and this probably isn't the place to ask about that. Asking about custom DSP or filtering algorithms won't get you good answers here because the skills needed to help you are not related to IoT.

Comment: Perhaps https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?